# Find the side of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

In the $\Delta ABC$ where $a = BC$, $b = CA$, $c = AB$ and $\angle A = \alpha$, $\angle B = \beta$ and $\angle C = \epsilon$.

Find side $c$, given that the $\angle C$ has a pointy angle and $a = 4$, $b = 7$ and $\sin \epsilon = \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: what is a pointy angle?

Comment: @papper do you mean for "pointy angle" to mean an   acute angle? (Less than 90 degrees?)

Comment: Do you know the law sine and the law of cosine?  Write both down.  What information do you have that you could plug into one of those rules to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Recall the law of sines:

$$
\frac{\sin \alpha}{a} = \frac{\sin \beta}{b} = \frac{\sin \epsilon}{c}
$$

And recall that the interior angles of a triangle add up to 180 degrees.

Using these two facts, you can create a system of equations to solve for the missing side, as follows.

$$
\epsilon = \arcsin(1/4) = 22.5 \text{ degrees}
$$
So we have
$$
\alpha + \beta + 22.5 = 180
$$
and
$$
\frac{\sin \alpha}{4} = \frac{\sin \beta}{7}
$$

Solve for either variable and reapply the law sines to get your answer.